# python imshow grayscale static color values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I understand using matplotlib.pyplot's imshow gives me a nice sketch that can be used to visualize matrices. My question is that when I want to visualize a matrix, the function adjusts the color density according to the values I am passing.
for example:

```
#define a numpy matrix with values between 0 and 1
k=numpy.array([
         [ 1.        ,  0.9701425 ,  0.99931483],
         [ 0.9701425 ,  1.        ,  0.97845444],
         [ 0.99931483,  0.97845444,  1.        ]])
#plot the matrix
plt.imshow(k,cmap=cm.gist_gray)
```

I get an image with a huge difference between 1 and .97 . if I do something like:

```
k[2][2]=.1
plt.imshow(k,cmap=cm.gist_gray)
```

I get a totally different picture. Is there any way to tackle this problem? is there any way to have an image where we have static color values instead of dynamically changing ones as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `vmin` and `vmax` keyword arguments of `imshow` as documented [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow). In particular, if you modify your `imshow` call to

```
plt.imshow(k, vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

the colours will be normalised as if there was a value `0` and a value `1` present in the data.