# Displaying binary numpy arrays as image in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 3x3 numpy array with 1s and 0s. For example:

```
[[0,1,0],
[0,0,1],
[1,0,0]
```

I am displaying it in black and white using matplotlib:

```
plt.imshow(X,interpolation='nearest',cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

When the array has both 1s and 0s, it produces a correct image.

But when all the values are 0s it displays all black, signifying an all 1 array, which is incorrect:

```
array = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] # displays black image (correct)
array = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]] #displays black image (incorrect)
```

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: Take a look at the `imshow()` docstring, and read about `vmin` and `vmax`.  (This is just a comment, because the question is probably a duplicate.)

Comment: While the question is not *exactly* the same, the answer here also answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119139/python-imshow-grayscale-static-color-values

Comment: I couldn't find similar questions - maybe I wasn't using the correct keywords. But I guess it would be inferred from those answers. It works now. Thanks!